# Instead of line break need a straight line

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I have used `LookupSet` in SSRS. How can I draw a line inside a row?

Currently, I've added line *breaks* by adding `vbcrlf`s. Instead of line break I need a line.

Is it possible?

Table1:

```
Person_ID   Name    Salary_Revisions
1           Test1   100
1           Test1   200
2           Test2   300
2           Test2   400
```

Table2:

```
Person ID                  Department        Organizations
-------------------------- ---------------- ---------------
1                          Physics             Test1
1                          Chemistry           Test2
2                          Maths               Test3
```

I would like to get the result like:

```
Person_ID             Name               Salary_Revisions       Department     Organization
--------------------- ------------------ ---------------------- ----------------------------
1                     Test1              100                    Physics          Test1
1                     Test1              200                    Chemistry        Test2
2                     Test2              300                    Maths            Test3
2                     Test2              400
```

To get like this I have added 3 data sets. Dataset1 contain Person_ID and name. Dataset1 added as dataset in Tablix Properties, means base dataset.
Second  **Dataset2**  contain person_ID and salary_revisions.
Third **Dataset3** contain person_id, Organizations,Department.

For getting salary_Revisions I have added a expression =Join(LookupSet(Fields!Person_ID.Value,Fields!Person_ID.Value,Fields!salary_revisions.Value, "Dataset2")," " + vbcrlf+vbcrlf).

For getting Department I have added a expression =Join(LookupSet(Fields!Person_ID.Value,Fields!Person_ID.Value,Fields!Department.Value, "Dataset3")," " + vbcrlf+vbcrlf).

For getting Organization I have added a expression =Join(LookupSet(Fields!Person_ID.Value,Fields!Person_ID.Value,Fields!Organization.Value, "Dataset3")," " + vbcrlf+vbcrlf).

By doing this I am facing an issue like while adding large Department it split into two lines. So corresponding Organization not comes in a same line.

Please find my result what I get.

```
Person_ID             Name               Salary_Revisions       Department     Organization
--------------------- ------------------ ---------------------- ----------------------------
1                     Test1              100                    Physics          Test1
1                     Test1              200                    Chemis           Test2     
                                                                   try           Test3
2                     Test2              300                    Maths          
2                     Test2              400
```

My Department **table width is 200 in database**. So I can't make much more design adjustments. can you please help me to implement like this.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few different ways to insert lines.

- Add a row with a black background color. Shrink the height and set CanGrow to False.
- Place a line image into the row and set it to repeatX (horizontally).

With each of these you can use expressions if needed to control when they appear. For example, if you have some sort of group ID, you can use the Previous function to check if you are starting a new group and just have the line show then.